# How to display in HTML with or without bootstrap a word aligned after and before the character ":"?

Tags: html, css

I want to know if I can display a string in HTML after the ':' with the same distance. For example I have the strings: Firstname: Josh and Time:12:12:01. I want to display them on the center of the screen and after the ':' I want to display the second part like the code below... Is that possible ?

```
<div>Lastname: Josh</div>

<div>Time:     12:12:01</div>
```

My problem is that Time is not exactly under Lastname ( T exactly under L ) and that I dont know how the J of Josh can displayed exacty at same height as the 1 of 12:12:01

Comment: So the goal is to have spaces and basically the second column to align vertically?

Comment: Okay that's a better way to ask, I'm not sure what you mean by the same height, but if you update your question to explain that, it will be a better question.  I think what you actually want is to use a `<dl></dl>`  with ` <dt>Lastname:</dt> <dd>Josh</dd>`.   Then you can use css to do the alignments.

Answer (score 1):

```css
dt {
  display: inline;
  
}
dd {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Last Name:</dt><dd>Josh</dd>
<dt>Time:</dt><dd>12:12:01</dd>
</dl>
```

This is very rough but you see that with dl you are explicitly having two kinds of elements in each item in the list. You can style each part separately.  You should be able to make that work for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```css
dt {
  display: inline;
  
}
dd {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Last Name:</dt><dd>Josh</dd>
<dt>Time:</dt><dd>12:12:01</dd>
</dl>
```

```css
dt {
  display: inline;
  
}
dd {
    margin-left: 80px;
    margin-top: -18px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
<dt>Last Name:</dt><dd>Josh</dd>
<dt>Time:</dt><dd>12:12:01</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score -1):

Plz check below code.

```css
.parent{display:flex}

.title{width:10%}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">Last Name:</div>
  <div>Josh</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="title">Time:</div>
  <div>12:12:01</div>
</div>
```